# With Pandoc, how to apply a style to a "fenced div" block?

Tags: formatting, pandoc

I use Pandoc to generate an output from a Markdown file to many outputs: html, word (.docx), latex, pdf, etc.

I tried using the "fenced div" feature to style differently some parts of the text.  For example:

---

blablabla.

:::: special

Some special text, *with markdown formatting*.

::::

---

To style that block with Html, it's fairly straight forward.  I have a `template.css` file that includes a `.special {background-color: #aaaaaa;}` line and it's done (it's referenced in my command line arguments).

I also have a `template.latex` file, but I'm less fluent in all things Latex.  I've tried in many ways and couldn't find how to tweak it to apply a style to pandoc fenced divs.  In the raw Latex file that it outputs, there's not even a command indicating that there was something there.  It's just ignored.

I've searched a long time for this answer, and I can't find any clue.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.se! I don't think this is a supported feature yet (if it ever will be). See https://github.com/jgm/pandoc/issues/5880 for some discussion.  The recommended approach seems to be to use [Lua filters](https://pandoc.org/lua-filters.html).

Comment: AFAIK you must use  ``::: {.special data-latex=""}``  and of course the "special" environment should have been already defined in the template preamble, the document class or some package, that I suspect that is not usable to export to another formats.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need a lua filter to process the fenced div:

```
function Div(el)
  if el.classes[1] == "special" then
    -- insert element in front
    table.insert(
      el.content, 1,
      pandoc.RawBlock("latex", "\\begin{Special}"))
    -- insert element at the back
    table.insert(
      el.content,
      pandoc.RawBlock("latex", "\\end{Special}"))
  end
  return el
end
```

This will transform the div to a latex environment:

```
blablabla.

\begin{Special}

Some special text, \emph{with markdown formatting.}

\end{Special}
```

You mustn't forget do define the environment in your template:

```
\usepackage{mdframed}
\newenvironment{Special}%
  {\begin{mdframed}[backgroundcolor=lightgray]}%
  {\end{mdframed}}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! If you didn't already know: You can output the AST with `--to native` to figure out how pandoc represents the elements internally

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This was very helpful. I came across with your answer after I posted a question on [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71088520/how-to-extend-pandoc). You gave me a great starting point to solve my problem. I modified your function for my needs and use `tcolorbox` instead of `mdframe`. See my answer to my own question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71119194/42659) . Just posting this here to have a cross reference. Cheers!

Answer (score 4):

Edit: should have noted this solution is for use in R/bookdown in particular, which I'm guessing has a Lua filter to handle this generically or something?

As Fran said in a comment, you must use the following code

```
::: {.special data-latex=""}
my special text *with markdown formatting*.
:::
```

For some reason at some point it stopped working to just name the style. You need that data-latex="" in there too to get it to work. But once you do that, the latex output will have the style added like so.

```
\begin{special}
Some special text
\end{special}
```

Then, as long as you've defined that style in the preamble, it will take on that style in the PDF.

For example, you could put the following in your preamble:

```
% special styling
\newenvironment{special}[0]{\par\leftskip=2em\rightskip=2em}{\par\medskip}
```

That would add left and right margin space for your style.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!